# how to read a yaml file in bash shell and iterate through a list inside

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I have this yaml file
I have a yaml file as below:

```
repos:
- REPO_NAME: A
  INGRESS_SUBDOMAIN: B
  DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH: C
  IMAGE_NAME: D
  MAJOR_VERSION: E
  MINOR_VERSION: F
```

the name of the file is f.yaml

in bash, I want to read the content of the file and then iterate through each repo, and to verify print the field "a"

I am dong this but it is not working

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

file_name="f.yaml"
for row in $(yq eval '.repos[]' "$file_name"); do
    REPO_NAME=$(echo "$row" | yq eval '.REPO_NAME' -)
    INGRESS_SUBDOMAIN=$(echo "$row" | yq eval '.INGRESS_SUBDOMAIN' -)
    DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH=$(echo "$row" | yq eval '.DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH' -)
    IMAGE_NAME=$(echo "$row" | yq eval '.IMAGE_NAME' -)
    MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo "$row" | yq eval '.MAJOR_VERSION' -)
    MINOR_VERSION=$(echo "$row" | yq eval '.MINOR_VERSION' -)

    ECHO $INGRESS_SUBDOMAIN
    ECHO $DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH
    ECHO $IMAGE_NAME
    ECHO $MAJOR_VERSION
    ECHO $MINOR_VERSION
done
```

right now it is printing a bunch of "null". How to fix it?

Comment: It would be _much_ more efficient to have a single yq instance output all the values you need instead of starting a separate copy of yq for each output. In jq, for example, this is readily done by generating NUL-delimited output.

Comment: Anyhow, `for row in` is the wrong tool to use here. It would be _much easier_ if yq had an equivalent to jq's `-c` / `--compact` mode, but I don't see that at a glance of its `--help` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`for row in` is unsuitable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) when you're iterating over values that have spaces, much less newlines, in them. Use `yq --nul-output` and a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop instead:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' repo_yaml; do
  repo_name=$(yq eval '.REPO_NAME' <<<"$repo_yaml")
  # ...and so forth
  echo "repo_name is $repo_name" >&2
done < <(yq --nul-output '.repos[]' <"$file_name")
```

---

Or, more efficiently, but running security risks if you don't trust your data not to be malicious, one can [use `yq -o=shell`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/shellvariables) to generate an assignment statement that can be `eval`ed in any POSIX-compliant shell to set all your variables at once:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' repo_eval; do
  eval "$repo_eval"
  echo "$REPO_NAME"
  echo "$INGRESS_SUBDOMAIN" # etc
done < <(yq -o=shell --nul-output '.repos[]' <"$file_name")
```

However, this is very ill-advised if your data could contain something like `PATH: /uploads/evil.com/rootkit:/bin:/usr/bin`; similar risks exist for `LD_PRELOAD` and other special values. (You could mitigate those risks by having the yq code prefix your key names with a lower-case substring: [only all-caps names](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) have special meanings to the shell and other POSIX-compliant OS-provided components).

Comment: does it work if we have comment in between the lines or at the end of the lines?

Comment: As long as your comments don't change the meaning of your YAML, they should have no impact. (That caveat is necessary because YAML is a poorly-designed syntax full of surprises -- but if you hit one of those surprises, it should be a problem with the input format, not with the code in this answer).

Comment: @AminBa (see https://ruudvanasseldonk.com/2023/01/11/the-yaml-document-from-hell for an introduction to a few of those corner cases, enough to make the point that YAML is often bizarre and surprising; for my own projects, where I have a choice, I use JSON or TOML or EDN or even XML, but stay as far away from YAML as I can).